# Strange Character in localized string

Tags: ios, localization

"sentenceFormat" = "%1$@ was first climbed on %3$@ and has a height of %2$@"; what does this localization string mean? especially %1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Notes for localizers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/NotesForLocalizers.html) for information on this syntax.

The `1$`/`2$`/... modifiers are used to re-arrange items in a format string, which may sometimes be required for certain languages/localizations.

In your example, the `3$` and `2$` reference the third and second arguments to `[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` (or whatever 'format' method was used) so that the third argument appears before the second.